# In rabbitmq console's queue section what does feature AD means?

Tags: rabbitmq

In the following screenshot of RabbitMQ management console, I am at Queues and Streams page. In the all queues table there is a column called Features. One of the feature is called `AD`. Could you guys please explain what does AD means?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means Auto-delete queue.

From the documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.auto-delete

> auto-delete
>
> If set, the queue is deleted when all consumers have finished using
> it. The last consumer can be cancelled either explicitly or because
> its channel is closed. If there was no consumer ever on the queue, it
> won't be deleted. Applications can explicitly delete auto-delete
> queues using the Delete method as normal.